# Errors while installing python packages

Tags: django, memcached, pip, easy-install

I 'm not able to install python packages from both `pip` and `easy_install`. There's some absurd kind of error that keeps popping up. Kindly help to rectify it.

I get the same errors while using `python setup.py install`.

Error while installing **django-memcached**

```
C:\Users\Praful\Desktop\django-redis-master>easy_install django-memcached
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\easy_install-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('distribute==0.6.27', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.27-py2.7.egg\setuptools\com
mand\easy_install.py", line 1915, in main
    with_ei_usage(lambda:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.27-py2.7.egg\setuptools\com
mand\easy_install.py", line 1896, in with_ei_usage
    return f()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.27-py2.7.egg\setuptools\com
mand\easy_install.py", line 1919, in <lambda>
    distclass=DistributionWithoutHelpCommands, **kw
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 112, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.27-py2.7.egg\setuptools\dis
t.py", line 222, in __init__
    for ep in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points('distutils.setup_keywords'):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.27-py2.7.egg\pkg_resources.
py", line 486, in iter_entry_points
    entries = dist.get_entry_map(group)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.27-py2.7.egg\pkg_resources.
py", line 2315, in get_entry_map
    self._get_metadata('entry_points.txt'), self
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.27-py2.7.egg\pkg_resources.
py", line 2101, in parse_map
    raise ValueError("Entry points must be listed in groups")
ValueError: Entry points must be listed in groups
```

Error while installing **python-memcache**

```
C:\Users\Praful\Desktop\mem>python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 24, in <module>
    "Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules",
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 112, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.27-py2.7.egg\setuptools\dis
t.py", line 222, in __init__
    for ep in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points('distutils.setup_keywords'):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.27-py2.7.egg\pkg_resources.
py", line 486, in iter_entry_points
    entries = dist.get_entry_map(group)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.27-py2.7.egg\pkg_resources.
py", line 2315, in get_entry_map
    self._get_metadata('entry_points.txt'), self
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.27-py2.7.egg\pkg_resources.
py", line 2101, in parse_map
    raise ValueError("Entry points must be listed in groups")
ValueError: Entry points must be listed in groups
```

Answer (score 8):

1. Find `get_entry_map(self, group=None):` into python\Lib\sitepackages\pkg_resources\__init__.py. Insert after `print self.egg_info`
2. Run `python setup.py` and look to the last printed - broken package.
   Remember it, later to install again. Delete the folder of broken
   package and folder `broken_package-version.dist-info`. Run again paragraph **2**, until the error disappears.
3. Remove changes from paragraph **1**.
4. `python setup.py install 'broken_package'`

Answer (score 1):

This error happened to me installing any package. My solution was going to my file explorer, typing in the path bar `%appdata%`, going to the `Python` folder, and deleting everything inside.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem to be caused by a misfometted entry_points.txt file in one instelled egg of mine.

It can be quite hard to track down which one is if there are many.

I managed to find that little ba#@!"d by creating and run setup.py for a dummy package:

**setup.py**

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name = "IWillFindYou",
    version = "0.1",
    packages = find_packages()
)
```

run this in debug mode would point to this line in pkg_resources.py

```
    def parse_map(cls, data, dist=None):
        [...]
            raise ValueError("Entry points must be listed in groups")
```

if you go back to the stack trace, you will see that parse_map is called here:

```
def get_entry_map(self, group=None):
    [...]
        ep_map = self._ep_map = EntryPoint.parse_map(
            self._get_metadata('entry_points.txt'), self
        )
```

evaluating `self.egg_info` will point up your evil egg so you can give a look to the entry_points.txt file.

If you are not handy with debugger, you may try to place  `print self.egg_info` in `get_entry_map` and look to the last guy printed.

Answer (score 0):

### My Resolution Approach

**Platform**:  windows 10, [ConEmu-Maximus5](https://conemu.github.io/)

- Delete virtual environment automatically created by `poetry install` command.

  > windows users can find the virtual environment folder in the path below
  >
  > *C:\Users\YOUR_PC_USERNAME\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs*
  >
  > (don't know of linux path)
- close terminal / command prompt
- open terminal / command prompt and navigate to project folder
- re run `poetry install`

I hope it helps...

#### How i encountered the error

It was my first time using poetry, while running `poetry install`, the process got interrupted. running the command again popped out the error.

Answer (score -1):

Could be a problem with `distribute`. I'd recommend re-installing Python.