# I can't install any package with pip anymore,

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I've always used pip in installing python packages but for some unexplained reason it just stopped working. I have tried the following but still not working

> - i upgraded pip
> - i rolled back pip
>
> -i uninstalled my python distribution and reinstalled/upgraded it. Here is a trace back of the kind of error i get whenever i try
>   installing a package with pip
>
> ```
> OS- windows 10
> ```

```
pip install profanity
    Collecting profanity
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f6/b4/07d53456462e26eee50abcae787c9380c01731ccc0b6c96233770e546989/profanity-1.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\MEME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2698, in get_entry_map
        ep_map = self._ep_map
      File "C:\Users\MEME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2669, in __getattr__
        raise AttributeError(attr)
    AttributeError: _ep_map
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\MEME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xg7obvs0\profanity\setup.py", line 72, in <module>
    ['profanity=profanity:main'],
  File "C:\Users\MEME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 128, in setup
    _install_setup_requires(attrs)
  File "C:\Users\MEME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 117, in _install_setup_requires
    (k, v) for k, v in attrs.items()
  File "C:\Users\MEME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 370, in __init__
    for ep in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points('distutils.setup_keywords'):
  File "C:\Users\MEME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 645, in iter_entry_points
    entries = dist.get_entry_map(group)
  File "C:\Users\MEME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2701, in get_entry_map
    self._get_metadata('entry_points.txt'), self
  File "C:\Users\MEME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2412, in parse_map
    raise ValueError("Entry points must be listed in groups")
ValueError: Entry points must be listed in groups
```

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   C:\Users\MEME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xg7obvs0\profanity\

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Errors while installing python packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17985110/errors-while-installing-python-packages)

Comment: None of the answers there are working for me

Comment: had that problem but with python 2.x [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28967785/attribute-error-installing-with-pip/30310206) solved it form me